# NSDateComponents not accepting input

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an NSDateCategory that is misbehaving. I am setting the year, month day but its result is completely different :

**variables :**
year = 2012
month = 10
day = 1

```
 + (NSDate *)dateWithYear:(NSInteger)year month:(NSInteger)month day:(NSInteger)day 
    {
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setYear:year];
        [components setMonth:month];
        [components setDay:day];
        NSDate *result =  [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

        return result;
    }
```

**NSLog output**
result = 2012-09-30 23:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line

```
[components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

do it:

NSDateComponents* components = [Calender components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                             fromDate:[NSDate date]];